# ffmpeg video to image sequence batch file

Tags: video, batch-file, ffmpeg, batch-processing

I'm using ffmpeg to convert .avi file into a .png image sequence. This one works just fine:

```
@ ECHO OFF

FOR %%A IN (*.avi) DO CALL :avi2png "%%A"

:avi2png
ffmpeg.exe -y -i %* -sameq -f image2 -c:v png "%%03d.png"

ECHO.
GOTO :EOF
```

---

But I want the script to extract the name without the extension from .avi file that is currently being processed. This is what the image sequence should look like: ***currentavi001.png***, ***currentavi002.png*** etc. The script I came up with isn't working:

```
@ ECHO OFF

FOR %%A IN (*.avi) DO CALL :avi2png "%%A"

:avi2png
ffmpeg.exe -y -i %* -sameq -f image2 -c:v png "%%~nA%%03d.png"

ECHO.
GOTO :EOF
```

---

I've tried both `%~nA` and `%%~nA`, but to no avail. The script returns this:

```
Couldn't open file : 
av_interleaved_write_frame(): Input/output error.
```

I'm a complete layman and would welcome every bit of help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't refer to the `%%A` variable in :avi2png. Try this:

```
@ ECHO OFF

set count=0
FOR %%A IN (*.avi) DO CALL :avi2png "%%A"
goto :eof

:avi2png
set /a count=count+1
set Ncount=00%count%
set Ncount=%Ncount:~-3%
ffmpeg.exe -y -i %* -sameq -f image2 -c:v png "%~n1%Ncount%.png"

ECHO.
GOTO :EOF
```

If you have one file in the current directory named `my_movie.avi` `ffmpeg` will create the png `my_movie001.png`.

When you `call` a label from a `for` loop, you can no longer use your original `for` loop variable (in this case %%A), instead `:label` is treated as a separate batch file and all variables on the line after the `:label` are treated as switches passed to a batch file.

So this...

```
Call :label one two thee
```

...works with this...

```
:label
Echo %1, %2, %3.
```

...to produce output like this:

```
one, two, three.
```

Just as if it were a stand-alone batch file.

Oh, also `%%A` and the like are never referred to by `%%A%%` (or `%A%`, a totally different variable). If you do that (and `%%A==Hello`) the result would be `Hello%`, and likely eat a character somewhere in your code, resulting in bizarre errors.

Comment: Thanks for the thorough response, James. For a complete noob like me, batch scripting is like a careful walk through a minefield. I'll try the code out when I get home and have access to my computer instead of just my phone.

Comment: @DaleCooper If my answer works for you, please select it as an answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

I could not get the above answer to work for me.  I take a 2 file approach with 1 line of code in each batch file to create an image every second with filename as ORIGINALFILENAME_#####.png. Update your paths as appropriate to the location of your ffmpeg.exe file and whatever you name the file to create the thumbs. I'm using windows 7 and this works for me.

Batch file in the folder with the video (name it whatever you want) to call the CreateThumbs.bat file:

**for /r %1 %%i in (*.avi) do "c:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\CreateThumbs.bat" %%i**

CreatThumbs.bat in ffmpeg folder to create thumbs:

**"c:\Program Files (x86)\ffmpeg\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -i %1 -r 1 -f image2 %~n1_%%05d.png**